# Pandas Groupby Problems with Calculating Column-Wise Quantiles with "quantile"

Tags: pandas, group-by, axis, quantile

i need to compute quantiles for a large DF across columns or column-wise along rows or "months" in my case. Apparently, the quantile function applied on just a df works using the key word "axis" but if you try and apply quantile using a groupby, it is rejected with an error:

```
TypeError: quantile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Here is the situation that the quantile works with data like this:

```
Num Num Num Quantile 0.5
5   6   4   5
4   1   2   2
3   9   7   7
7   2   8   7
5   5   4   5
```

But, if I add more columns with a groupby statement to find the same quantile(0.5, axis=1), then I get the error shown above. Please help and thank you. My actual data looks like this below:

```
    site    month   Num Num Num Quantile 0.5
0   A       8       5   6   4   5
1   A       9       4   1   2   2
2   A      10       3   9   7   7
3   A      11       7   2   8   7
4   A      12       5   5   4   5
5   B       8       3   7   5   5
6   B       9       6   9   0   6
7   B      10       4   1   3   3
8   B      11       8   3   0   3
9   B      12       5   6   8   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises from the fact that [`pd.DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) are not the same functions. The first one has an `axis` parameter, the second one does not. Hence the error.

When you think about it, it is perfectly logical that the second function does not have this option. Suppose we do:

```
groups = df.groupby('site')

for group in groups:
    print(group[1])

  site  month  Num  Num.1  Num.2
0    A      8    5      6      4
1    A      9    4      1      2
2    A     10    3      9      7
3    A     11    7      2      8
4    A     12    5      5      4

  site  month  Num  Num.1  Num.2
5    B      8    3      7      5
6    B      9    6      9      0
7    B     10    4      1      3
8    B     11    8      3      0
9    B     12    5      6      8
```

Now ask yourself the question which axis could generate a `qauntile` that is meaningfully related to `A | B`. The answer surely is *column-wise*. I could get a `quantile` of `Num` for A, or `Num.1`. E.g.:

```
print(groups.quantile())
      month  Num  Num.1  Num.2
site                          
A      10.0  5.0    5.0    4.0
B      10.0  5.0    6.0    3.0
```

It wouldn't make sense to say, let's get the quantile *row-wise* for A at row `0` (and pretend that this has anything to do with `A` *as a grouped value as distinct from* `B`). Indeed, you don't need a `groupby` for that at all.

Sidenote: you will have noticed that your columns `Num, Num, Num` have turned into `Num, Num.1, Num.2` in my examples. This conversion takes place automatically when you read from the clipboard (`pd.read_clipboard`). In general, having multiple columns with duplicate names is very bad practice and might get you into all sorts of problems with various operators. So, I strongly advice you to rename them.